# Periodic Boundary Conditions for Persistent Homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

Is there a standard method/library for implementing persistent homology on points with periodic boundary conditions? For example, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcrGG.png), where red lines indicate the desired location of periodicity. In this example, such periodicity implies that the data points (shown in blue) should contribute an $H_1$ homology in the persistence diagram.

I imagine one approach would simply be to map the data points from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an $n$ dimensional torus in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, though ideally I would like persistent homology to restrict itself to the surface of the torus.

Comment: Some software packages let you input a precomputed distance matrix, so you can input the quotient metric instead.

Comment: Hi @JHF, using a distance matrix sounds like a good idea. What exactly is a quotient metric? Sorry if my background is lacking. I was thinking of using the following metric:
$d(x_1,x_2)=\min\left [ x_2-x_1,(x_1-\ell_1)+(\ell_2-x_2) \right ]$, where $x_2>x_1$ and $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the locations of the boundaries.

Comment: By quotient metric I just mean the induced metric on the quotient space.  Your proposed metric should work.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the insight!